# Revenue Confusion

Tags: app-store-connect

I use Appannie analytics to see my earnings and I am confused about the revenue. I guess Appannie shows the revenue after Apple 30% deduction (because it shows $1.40 for my $2 app). In Feb Appannie shows my sale was $1,371.57, but I received 669.22 from Apple. Can you please tell me how much Apple is taking out of payments and how much TAX they are collecting for a US based account.

Comment: What does iTunnes Connect show?

Comment: Can we assume you only sell your one app on the US App Store (so currency exchange considerations can be ignored)? My guess is Appnannie is pulling the store data instead of processing the actual financial reports.

Comment: Could they be doing 30 percent tax withholding on your 70 percent of the sales?